# Appending a string with html-code

Tags: php, javascript, html, onchange

I'm trying to build a snippet which will later be inserted into a bigger piece of code.

Everythings working fine so far, but there's one problem:
I have not figured out how to implement the ONCHANGE-part.
The value is detected successfully, but I just don't get a fine index.php?day=23424234 combination. I suppose it's something about escape characters?

Would anyone help me?

```
    $dayChoser = ' <form name="day">
<select ONCHANGE="location = index.php?day=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
';
    foreach ($tageArray as $ts) {
        $tempDay = date('m/d/Y', $ts);
        $dayChoser.='<option value=' . $ts . '>' . $tempDay . '</option>';
    }
    $dayChoser.='</select> </form>';
```

Comment: What is $tageArray variable? Guess some array, right?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - I think $tageArray might be an elephant. :P

Comment: Might be any data type or even not declared, I don't see what it is so I just guess. Because it has been used in foreach, doesn't mean that it is an array type or maybe I didn't see something.

Answer (score 3):

It's more a Javascript syntax problem. The `index.php?day=` part should be a string, and everything after the `this.` is an expression.

```
$dayChoser = ' <form name="day">
    <select ONCHANGE="document.location = \'index.php?day=\' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
';
```

The quotes for JS in the HTML attribute just need \ escaping, because the outer quotes for PHP are already single quotes.

Comment: You still forgot to break the quoted literal up.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<select ONCHANGE="location = index.php?day=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

to

```
<select ONCHANGE="window.location = \'index.php?day=\' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ONCHANGE="location = \'index.php?day=\'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
                             ^^              ^^^
```

You need the path in quotes within the in-line javascript, then have it concatenate the selected value.

*Changes denoted by carets*

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around the location value that you want to set.

```
$dayChoser = ' <form name="day"><select ONCHANGE="location = \'index.php?day=\' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + \';\'">
```

';

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dayChoser = ' <form name="day"><select ONCHANGE=\'location.href="index.php?day="+this.value;\'>';
```